# How to define identity of intension?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language

In philosophy, there is much mention of the intension/extension distinction. Two properties can be extensionally equal but not intensionally equal. It is very easy to define when two properties are extensionally, but I have never seen a satisfactory definition of intensional identity. Has anyone defined it?

Comment: Can you mention what unsatisfactory ones you've seen and briefly explain why you find them unsatisfactory?

Comment: It's possible for two things to be equivalent without being equal; one simple-minded definition of equivalent intensions is they give equal extensions; I'll be interested to see what answers come up - good question.

Comment: Have you tried with the review in SEP: [Intensional Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intensional/) ? There are many references to recent developments.